# How do I get Word 2007 to stop changing the font when pasting special characters

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2007, special-characters

When pasting text as "unformatted unicode text" in Word 2007, some special characters will be rendered in a different font, even when the current font at the place of insertion has these characters.

Some characters that cause this are ɑ (latin small letter alpha, unicode 0251) and ɡ (latin small letter g, 0261), which typically appear in MS Mincho or SimSun.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: Are you using a localized version of Word/Windows?

Comment: Yes and no. On my own computer, I use English Office/Word but Swedish Windows Vista. At the office, I believe it's English/English, but I can't check right now. The problem persists on both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Word installed on this machine to test this atm, but my usual low-tech way to strip formatting from text before pasting into word is to paste & re-copy it from notepad before feeding it into Word.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on the keyboard. A dialog box will then appear asking you how to paste your text. Choose "Unformatted Text". It will insert the contents of the Clipboard as text without any formatting. I have tried it with the characters you mentioned, and everything works fine as expected.